# Retrieve data from firebase database

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am trying to retrieve data from the firebase database. Here is my code

```
- (FIRDatabaseReference *) referenceFromURL:(NSString *)databaseUrl{

    commentsRef = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceFromURL:databaseUrl];
    return commentsRef;
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [commentsRef
     observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
     withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
         NSDictionary * post = snapshot.value;

     }];

}
```

The reference is successfully built by the database but the code written in block

> "NSDictionary * post = snapshot.value;"

didn't execute.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the beginning of viewWillAppear, what is `commentsRef`'s value?

Comment: its a reference variable.... FIRDATABASEREFERENCE * comments ref;
and I also checked with inserting a breakpoint.

Comment: It's possible that the URL is incorrect, that you don't have permission to read from the given endpoint, or that some other read error is taking place. Can you add `withCancelBlock` to catch and log any possible errors? That would provide more insight into why you aren't able to retrieve the snapshot value. See [the first example in the Firebase guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-start) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily. If you want to fetch all info using this you can do this. Make sure you have made your db public

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref;
```

Define Property on interface then

```
 self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
     [self.ref observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
            NSDictionary *usersDict = snapshot.value;

            NSLog(@"Information : %@",usersDict);
        }];
```

If you want to fetch specific portion using this you can do this

```
 [[self.ref child:@"results"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        NSDictionary *usersDict = snapshot.value;

        NSLog(@"Info : %@",usersDict);



    }];
```

My Fetched Json From Firebase

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      },
{
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      },
{
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      },
{
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will be cool if you can update to firebase 3.0.

If you want to take a look to [MakinGIANST - Post](http://blog.makingiants.com/firebase-database-chat-experience/) about firebase to get more info about how to query and use the new api.

It's for Android but its in Kotlin so will look like Swift